# inclusion-exclusion principle - possible ways

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve out this problem. I have a square net and I need to get from the point $(0,0)$ to $(15,20)$, but I can only go up or to the right, and I mustn´t go through $(5,6), (10,9), (7,13)$ and $(12,15)$. I think I might start with counting all the possibilities ($\binom{35}{15}$?) but I have no idea, how to continue. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, if there is no restriction there are $\binom{35}{15}$. Now count the forbidden paths. There are for example $\binom{11}{5}\binom{10}{24}$ paths that go through $(5,6)$. Do the same for the other $3$ points. Add. This overcounts the bads. We must subtract, for example, the paths that go through $(5,6)$ **and** $(10,9)$. And so on, carefully. There will be a need to add back the paths that go through $3$ of our target points. To make our lives easier, there is none that goes through all $4$.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by (10 choose 24) ? Didn´t you mean 24 choose 10? Anyway, thanks very much, so I have the A , B and C paths, but now, how can I get |A∩B| ? thanks

Comment: Sorry, typo, and I was away so did not get your message until now. And it is $4$ forbidden places, not $3$. For $A\cup B$ it is $\binom{11}{5}\binom{8}{3}\binom{16}{5}$. Not all combinations of $2$ are possible, for example there is no path that goes through $(10,9)$ and $(7,13)$. Cannot say much more in comment, and it would be best if you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those are all the possibilities. You need to calculate the cardinal of $T\setminus (A\cup B\cup C)$ where $T$ is the set of all paths ($|T|=\binom{35}{15}$), $A$ is the set of paths that pass by $(5,6)$,$B$ is the set of paths that pass by $(10,9)$ and $C$ is the set of paths that pass by $(7,13)$.
For I.E principle you know that $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|B\cap C|-|A\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$, so you need a way to calculate paths that pass by two or more points.
 So, as a hint draw a grid and put $k\geq 2$ points and see that when you do it you will generate $k+1$ subproblems that are a lot like the problem of calculate all possibilities (that you did in your question), for gluing together the subproblems use the multiplication principle.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks you very much, now, how do I count |A∩B| ?

Comment: That is what i have asked you to draw. Do you see how pass by $(5,6)$ and later by $(10,9)$ generates 3 subgrids in the original one?

Comment: so for example  |A∩B| would be (all the posibilities from 0,0 to 5,6) * (all the possibilities from 5,6 to 10,9) * (all the possibilities from 10,9 to 15,20) ?

Comment: Yes! That is indeed the way. Notice that you know how to count each of them, you did it in the question.

Comment: thank you! one more thing i´m not sure about. When André Nicolas was talking about forbidden paths, as the example, he wrote (11 choose 5)*(10 choose 24). Shouldn´t that be 24 choose 10 instead?

Comment: Yes, he meant that.

Comment: Thank you. You really helped me a lo., I really appreciate it.